# Regex: pattern for simple division string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that follows this pattern:

`2/9 (22%)`

where the `2` or the `9` could contain 1 or more digits. I need to parse out those two integers, so I came up with this pattern:

```
String patternString = "([0-9]+)/([0-9]+).*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stat);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0));
    int j = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
}
```

But this crashes with the following error:

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "2/9 (22%)"`

which means that it is matching the entire string on the 0th group.

I've also tried placing the `/` character inside of `[/]`, but same result.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `group(1)` and `group(2)`.

`group(0)` is the entire string, which you actually stated in the question

Comment: Ack! Thanks. Didn't realize that.

Answer (score 2):

Use group 1. Group 0 will match the whole string

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
```